# GRAILS GORM is showing wrong results while querying with Enum Types

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have a domain object called Request that has a Status ENUM with the below values

```
Request {
  Status status
}

enum Status{
     Processed('processed')
     Rejected('rejected')
     InProgress('progress')

     String name
     Status(name){
         this.name=name
     }
}
```

When I query the Request object as `Request.findByStatus(Status.Processed)` I get back all the records including the ones with status rejected and progress. Can someone tell me what exactly is going wrong or what do i need to fix the same. I also tried querying with criteria  as below

```
Request.createCriteria().list { 
    eq('status',Status.Processed)
}
```

but still it gives me all the records.Any pointers??

Comment: Turn on sql logging and see what is being generated

Answer (score 1):

Generally Enums are capitalized (to avoid the confusion with normal String implementations). It should work as expected if the setup is like:

```
enum Status{
     PROCESSED('processed')
     REJECTED('rejected')
     INPROGRESS('progress')

     private final String name

     Status(name){this.name=name}
     String value(){name}
}

[new Request(status: Status.INPROGRESS),
 new Request(status: Status.REJECTED),
 new Request(status: Status.PROCESSED)]*.save()

assert Request.findByStatus(Status.REJECTED) instanceof Request
assert Request.findByStatus(Status.REJECTED).status == Status.REJECTED
assert Request.findByStatus(Status.REJECTED).status.value==Status.REJECTED.value
```

Comment: I had tried the same but no luck still i keep getting all the records when i do Request.findByStatus(Status.REJECTED)